# How to bulk/batch insert in cassandra using cqlengine?

Tags: python, cassandra, bulkinsert, cqlsh

I want to use bulk insert in my cassandra for the performance purposes. I have 10 grabber servers which are producing data and insert them in master server.
What I exactly want to do is that, instead of direct insert to the database, every grabber server collect data and insert to the main server once. I don't know if it's batch insert or bulk insert or both. how to do this?
I'm using python and cql engine and cassandra in windows 8
I've found this batch insert but I don't know it's what I should do or not:
http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/references/cql/BATCH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the cqlengine batch query docs:
https://cqlengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/queryset.html#batch-queries